# How to setup my xmpp server with ejabberd in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

- `ejabberd` I was installed the newest ejabberd with the suggestion step by step and set the host name like `jyhu` using like `test@jyhu`.
- `xmpp` I was download the latest XMPPFramework from github .
- `iOS` Setup the project fowllowing :

  1. `init xmppStream`

     ```
      self.xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
      [self.xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
      [self.xmppStream setHostName:@"127.0.0.1"];
      [self.xmppStream setHostPort:5280];
     ```
  2. `setup JID`

     ```
     [self.xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:self.userName]];
     ```
  3. `connect`

     ```
     if (![self.xmppStream connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
     {
           NSLog(@"%@", [error userInfo]);
     }
     ```

Then setup some releated delegate methods .

When I run my project, the ejabberd log shown like

> 2015-08-28 10:45:29.890 [info] <0.436.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:299 (#Port<0.3800>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:62419 -> 127.0.0.1:5280
>   2015-08-28 10:45:29.890 [info] <0.442.0>@ejabberd_http:init:157 started: {gen_tcp,#Port<0.3800>}

And the delegate will going :

1. `- (void)xmppStreamWillConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender`
2. `- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender socketDidConnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket`
3. `- (void)xmppStreamDidStartNegotiation:(XMPPStream *)sender`
4. `- (void)xmppStreamDidDisconnect:(XMPPStream *)sender withError:(NSError *)error`

> But the most important method `- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender` will never be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect on port 5280, which is reserved for XMPP Bosh and Websocket transport. You likely wants to connect instead on the standard XMPP port, which is 5222.